Kentico 13 - Could not load file or assembly 'AngleSharp' or one of its dependencies after applying latest hotfix
After applying the latest Hotfix (v13.151) to my admin project, the log shows no errors. I successfully rebuilt the solution but when I try to launch the admin site I get:
Could not load file or assembly 'AngleSharp' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Seems it's looking for v17 but I only have v14.
There has been no mention of Anglesharp redirects or anything else Anglesharp related in the hotfix log

This is most likely due to a package mismatch in another project within your solution.  I'd suggest reviewing what packages you have in your solution, force remove that reference from the project, and then adding that reference back using at least version 0.17.1.
You could also check your web.config in the admin project to see if there isn't a binding reference to that library as well.  If so, I'd suggest updating that manually to the proper version after you reinstall the package from Nuget.

Thanks Brendan. Not sure what the offending library was as I ended up manually updating around 20 dlls from /packages to /cms/bin

Rory, that's good to hear you got it working, but your solution is only temporary.  When you go to build again or clone that code repo to another machine, it will break.  I'd highly recommend NOT manually copying any DLLs as it will only cause problems later.
